# Silverlight 5 Custom Download Image

Tags: silverlight, graphical-logo

I've a web ap, which makes use of SL5 plugins, I'd like to replace the default 'To view this content please install..' image, which comes up on a screen when SL isn't installed with my own one, pointing to the same URL. Wonder if I can to do so from a legal standpoint of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak from a legal standpoint, but Microsoft encourage you to customize the Silverlight install process, and integrate it with your site. For example Tim Heuer has written about this [a few times](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/09/08/silverlight-install-experience-too-hard.aspx) [and gives examples](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/25/creating-a-great-silverlight-deployment-experience.aspx) of alternate images. Here's [an official guide](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/pre-loaders-and-installers/silverlight-install-and-upgrade-experience#customizeinstall). In particular they say

> You should replace this image with your own content, or incorporate it into your content.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you are free to do so.

Also: with a little bit of looking on the web you can also easily find custom preloaders to get rid of the standard fuzzy blue spots progress circle.

[Here is one of those](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/preloading_displaying_image_pg1.htm)

[And another one](http://hackingsilverlight.blogspot.com/2010/03/no-silverlight-and-preloader.html)